# Check if a file that has been opened with fopen has been closed

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

Is it possible for check if a file has already closed?

I have opened a file using `fopen()` and closed using `fclose(fd)`.

This file gets opened and closed during the running of the program. However, the user can terminate the program by doing a `ctrl-c`.

When I go to my cleanup routine, I don't know if the file is in a open or closed state. So if I try and do a `fclose(fd)` twice, it will stack dump.

Some ideas I have been throwing around:

> 1. Add a state to the file to be either opened or closed, and then check that state, means more work for such a simple job.
> 2. Don't do anything as the OS will cleanup automatially when the program ends.
> 3. Is there is the access function, but that will just checks the mode.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Adding a state (the first option) would add a race condition unless you mask Ctrl+C signal while the state is synchronized with the file.

Comment: why can't you set `fd` _(strange name, btw)_ to `NULL` after closing ?

Comment: It is more related to the libc (often Glibc, but could be [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) etc...) than to the compiler.

Comment: Have a state var `#define`d as `OPEN` and `CLOSE`. Whenever you call `fopen` in your code, set the state as `Current_State = OPEN;` and when you call `fclose` in your code, set the state as `Current_State = CLOSE;` and use that `current_state` variable as and when needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, glibc doesn't provide a method to validate a `FILE*` variable.

Keeping some kind of state or just setting `fd` to `NULL` works, but you have to be careful not to get into your cleanup routine just after closing the file, but before resetting `fd`. As Ctrl+C sends a signal (SIGINT) to a program, you can just block the signal while the file is being closed and fd is being reset. So, your `fclose` in the main program should look like:

```
// 1. Block SIGINT
sigset_t old_mask, to_block;
sigemptyset(&to_block);
sigaddset(&to_block, SIGINT);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &to_block, &old_mask);

// 2. Close the file and reset fd
fclose(fd);
fd = NULL;

// 3. Restore signal handling
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &old_mask, NULL);
```

And in your clean-up routine you should just check `fd`:

```
if (fd != NULL) fclose(fd);
```

If your program is multithreaded, you should use `pthread_sigmask` instead.

In your case, simple call of `fcloseall()` in the cleanup routine would be much easier.

As for the second option meant in your question, about doing nothing - well, the OS will clean-up everything for your program. Then only drawback is that if there were opened write streams, some data may be not written to disk. But maybe in case of Ctrl+C it's just ok.

Comment: Whats is *AFAIK* btw?

Comment: As far as I know, AFAIK is an abbreviation for 'As far as I know' :)

Answer (score 4):

It seams to me that there is a little confusion in your mind.

File handlers, used with `fopen`, `fclose`, `f...` functions are *process scope*. I.e., they are valid within application (normally).

Two things can happen when you open a file: you succeed or not. If you succeed, you may be using file exclusively or shared with other processes. If you fail, maybe another process is already using file. Search `_fsopen`.

When process ends, *normally* or interrupted (as with `Ctrl+C`), OS releases resources associated with process, sooner or later. This applies to file handlers, memory, ...

Regarding your question, whether your application end normally or with `Ctrl+C`, unclosed file handlers will be released by OS.

Whenever your application starts, you need to open file handlers you need. OS will not keep them open for you.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem in a different situation (no race condition). So this solution covers both the question in the title and the one asked by ant.

When `fclose(fd)` is called the internal `fd->_fileno` low level I/O-file descriptor is set to -1 (or an other invalid unix file descriptor). So one could check using `fileno(fd)>=0` to verify if `fd` is still a valid stream (my original problem).

When `CTRL-C` is pressed the process receives a signal refereed as `SIGINT` and executes the corresponding signal handler (e.g. a predefined function). One should never try to do anything involving the program state (except for atomic settable variables, e.g. flags) in a signal handler, because the signal might arrive in any situation, so even while `fclose(fd)` is executed in glibc (so `fd->_fileno` is undefined during the execution of the handler). Because of this the canonical way here is to set a flag triggering the shutdown and return. The main application then needs to check this flag sufficiently often, and, if it is set, cleans up and exit.

This program finishes after `CTRL-C` is pressed, without leading to any fd cleaned up by the system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char interrupted=0;

void exit_handler(int sig){
    interrupted=1;
}

int main(char** argc, int argv)
{
    FILE *fd;

    signal(SIGINT, exit_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, exit_handler);

    while(1){
        fd=fopen("filepath.file","w");
        char *tst_str="Test String";
        if(fwrite(tst_str,1,11,fd)!=11)
            printf("Writing Error occured\n");

        if (fileno(fd)>=0){
            printf("FD Closed. (1)\n");
            fclose(fd);
        }
        if (fileno(fd)>=0){
            printf("FD Closed. (2)\n");
            fclose(fd);
        }
        if(interrupted)
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("Done.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it help you, just some suggestions:

You can check file open by your process using process id.

1. [`pid_t getpid(void);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpid),  return the process ID of the calling process.
2. Next pass this PID to [`pfiles`](http://illumos.org/man/1/pfiles) command.

Second:

You can call  [`int fcloseall (void);`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-Streams.html) before program terminates.

> This function causes **all open streams of the process to be closed and
>   the connection to corresponding files to be broken**. All buffered data
>   is written and any buffered input is discarded. The fcloseall function
>   returns a value of 0 if all the files were closed successfully, and
>   EOF if an error was detected.

Comment: On Linux you can use (and check programmatically) the `/proc/self/fd/` and `/proc/self/fdinfo/` directories from inside the process, or `/proc/$PID/fd/` etc from outside. `/proc/` is accessed by `pfiles`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is I read in manual `pfiles` command read proc-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

```
int sig_int(int signo)
{
    if(fdOpen)
       fclose(fd);
    abort();
}
```

Then add this to `main`:

```
static volatile fdOpen = 0;
static FILE *fd;//I guess
if(signal(SIGINT,sig_int) == SIG_ERR)
    printf("signal(SIGINT) error\n");

if((fd =fopen("your_file_name","flag_you_need")) != NULL)
    fdOpen = 1;
```

Do this before fcolse:

```
sigset_t newmask,oldmask;
sigemptyset(&newmask);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGINT);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);//BLOCK SIGINT
```

And set `fdOpen = 0 ;`after you close file normally`//SIGINT will not interrupt us now.`

Then

```
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&oldmask,NULL);//RESET signal mask
```

So we do some clean jobs and  then exit the program at `sig_int`.

Comment: The only problem here is when sig_int() gets called after the normal `fclose`, but before `fdOpen = 0;`.